# search/replace contains ‘x’ and does not contain ‘y'

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

Does anyone know a way (regex search or plugin or anything other mac tools) i could search for a string i want to replace but only if another string is not on the same line.

This is Html code and i would like to search all files in a project that contain string `<button` and change it to `<button type="button"` as long as it doesn't contain the string `type` on the same line?

Currently using either sublime and atom but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a regex search and replace in Sublime, using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Select **`Find → Replace…`** and in the `Find What:` box enter

```
(<button)(?!.*?type)
```

and in the `Replace With:` box enter

```
<button type="button"
```

Make sure the Regular Expression button is selected on the far left at the top.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/tB4mU5/2) is a demo. Basically, the first group (delineated by parentheses `( )`) finds the opening part of the tag - simple enough. The second group `(?!.*?type)` is a negative lookahead `?!` that searches for any character `.` repeated zero or more times and giving back reluctantly `*?` followed by the word `type`. The first group will match only if the second group does not match.